# Dynamically adding listeners in Google Maps where iframe src is set differently for each marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, event-listener

Hi I've read the articles and the excellent piece on scope and closures by Robert Nyman.
 However i cannot get this to work. I'm trying to assign a mouseover event to various markers and then set an iframe src depending on the marker moused over. I get the infamous last entry for every mouseover event. I've played with it for the better part of a few days and not even the 'thinking fluid' is helping :). Any guidance appreciated

for(var i=0; i

```
                        var latlngr = new google.maps.LatLng(mylatd,mylongd);
                        markerno = "marker_"+i;
                        markerarray[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                                position: latlngr,
                                                                map: map,
                                                                title:myname
                                                                });
                             google.maps.event.addListener(markerarray[i], 'mouseover', function(markerno)
                              {return function()
                                {
                               mysrc = 'http://adds.aviationweather.gov/metars/index.php?submit=1&station_ids='+myicao+'&chk_metars=on&chk_tafs=on&std_trans=translated';
                               alert (mysrc);
                               $('#weather').attr({src: mysrc});
                              }(markerno)
                              });



                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve your problem by wrapping your block in a self-executing wrapper function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < someLength; i++) (function(i){
  // Your internal code here. i will be bound to it's value in the correct context
})(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

'Thinking fluid doesn't work' - clarity of thought in the mornings does. I resolved it by looking a little more closely at what i was doing. I had a closure issue and wasn't even passing the correct variable into the function i was creating. This works - but thanks for the ideas.

for(var i=0; i

```
                            var latlngr = new google.maps.LatLng(mylatd,mylongd);
                                            markerarray[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                                    position: latlngr,
                                                                    map: map,
                                                                    title:myname
                                                                    });
                                 google.maps.event.addListener(markerarray[i],                  'mouseover', 
                                  function(myair)
                                  {return function()
                                  {
                                   mysrc = 'http://adds.aviationweather.gov/metars/index.php?submit=1&station_ids='+myair+'&chk_metars=on&chk_tafs=on&std_trans=translated';

                                   $('#weather').attr({src: mysrc});
                                  };}

                                  (myicao));
                       }
```